# PHP can't load XML file from http://comment.bilibili.tv

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml, file-get-contents

I use the simple code below to load XML file from Internet and read it:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

or this code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
```

or tis code:

```
$doc = file_get_contents($url);
```

They work well except for one website: http://comment.bilibili.tv/

If the $url is like "http://comment.bilibili.tv/681965.xml",
file_get_contents() will get messy code and simplexml_load_file() will get empty object.

But if I download it to my local HDD, and change the $url to "681965.xml",
the code works.

So what's the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the error you're seeing. What does "get messy code" mean? Do you see an error message? Have you tried doing something like `$doc = file_get_contents($url); file_put_contents('test.txt', $doc);` and opening it up in a text editor? If so, can you describe what you found, or show us a small example?

Answer (score 1):

The response from comment.bilibili.tv is compressed using the [DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm, as you can see from the `Content-Encoding` header when you request it in a web browser.

I'm not sure why PHP doesn't pick up on this when you request it and handle it for you but you can get round it by passing the content through `gzinflate` after calling `file_get_contents`. Then you could load the content into `DOMDocument` or `simplexml_load_string` as appropriate.

```
$content = gzinflate(file_get_contents("http://comment.bilibili.tv/681965.xml"));
```

You can also use [compression filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filters.compression.php) to build a URL that you can pass directly to `simplexml_load_file` or `DOMDocument::load`.

```
$url = "php://filter/zlib.inflate/resource=http://comment.bilibili.tv/681965.xml";

$doc = simplexml_load_file($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);

$doc = file_get_contents($url);
```